# I cannot recognize this kanji after my name

Tags: kanji, handwriting

This morning I received a parcel with some gifts from my Japanese friends and there it was written ミゲル(?), which is my name (Miguel) and some handwritten kanji that I cannot recognize (only the 木 radical on the left, but I don't find any similar kanji when I search by radical). Maybe it varies too much from handwritten script to computer script.

[image]

I tried to draw it in some mobile app that I have, but maybe my calligraphy is too bad; it does not produce any result. Could you tell me what kanji it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the kanji 様{さま}, used here as an honorific after your name.

Answer (score 3):

It's 様{さま}, which means "the honorable". It could be considered a much more respectful equivalent of さん.

Answer (score 3):

Although "which kanji it is?" was already answered, I'd like to expand on the "I cannot recognize this kanji" part.

Recognizing handwritten kanji takes time, but **guessing by context** may help.

In this case, the kanji appears next to, and after, your name. Frequent kanji or words in that position are honorific suffixes: ちゃん, さん, 君, 様, 先生. You could then search for those in a dictionary and compare to the handwritten one.

(Another example: the largest kanji on packaging would probably be related to the item inside, such as 筆.)

Comment: First I thought it was ミゲルへ (for Miguel) and I began searching kanji equivalents to the particle へ (not necessarily another particle, but words that mean "belonging to" or something like that). I always have seen most honorific suffixes written in hiragana, so I didn't think of it. Thank you for your explanation.